# data.table generate multiple columns and summarize them

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to learn data.table syntax.  I have most of the basics of simple summarizations but I am not getting how to use data.table to generate new columns from an existing column and summarize.

Here's a MWE example where I use dplyr and base tools to make multiple columns from one and thn summarize by grouping variables:

**Current Input**

```
##    fact1 fact2 X0
## 1      b     2  9
## 2      a     2  6
## 3      b     1  7
## 4      c     2  3
## 5      a     1  8
## 6      a     1  4
## 7      a     1  5
## 8      a     1  1
## 9      b     1  2
## 10     b     2 10
```

**Base + dlyr Code**

```
set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(
    fact1 = factor(sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 10, TRUE)), 
    fact2 = factor(sample(1:2, 10, TRUE)), 
    X0 = sample(1:10, 10)
)

add <- function(x, y) x + y
z <- sample(1:10, 6, FALSE)

library(dplyr)

z %>% 
    lapply(., add, dat[, 'X0']) %>%
    do.call(cbind, .) %>%
    cbind(dat, .) %>%
    data.frame() %>%
    group_by(fact1, fact2) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

**Desired output**

```
## Source: local data frame [5 x 9]
## Groups: fact1
## 
##   fact1 fact2 X0 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
## 1     a     1 18 42 22 26 46 30 34
## 2     a     2  6 12  7  8 13  9 10
## 3     b     1  9 21 11 13 23 15 17
## 4     b     2 19 31 21 23 33 25 27
## 5     c     2  3  9  4  5 10  6  7
```

While I'm asking for a data.table specific solution I think seeing base and dplyr etc. solutions that are clever may make this question appeal to a broader reader.

Comment: If you like having an `add` function, you might try magrittr, which includes it alongside similar fns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be better ways

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, paste0("X", 1:6):= lapply(z, add, X0),
           ][, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(fact1, fact2)]

#    fact1 fact2 X0 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
# 1:     b     2 19 31 21 23 33 25 27
# 2:     a     2  6 12  7  8 13  9 10
# 3:     b     1  9 21 11 13 23 15 17
# 4:     c     2  3  9  4  5 10  6  7
# 5:     a     1 18 42 22 26 46 30 34
```

Comment: You don't need `dat$` inside `dat`; and to match the OP's sorting, one could switch the last part to `keyby=.(fact1,fact2)`. This can also be done in one `[]`, like `setDT(dat)[, lapply(lapply(c(0,z), add, X0),sum),keyby=.(fact1,fact2)]`, though I suppose that might not generalize to the OP's use case.

Comment: I liked @Frank's addition as well. +1

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` option is

```
dat[paste0('X', 1:6)] <- Map(add, list(dat$X0), z)
aggregate(.~fact1+fact2, dat, FUN=sum)
#  fact1 fact2 X0 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
#1     a     1 18 42 22 26 46 30 34
#2     b     1  9 21 11 13 23 15 17
#3     a     2  6 12  7  8 13  9 10
#4     b     2 19 31 21 23 33 25 27
#5     c     2  3  9  4  5 10  6  7
```

Or in a single step

```
aggregate(.~fact1+fact2, cbind(dat, mapply(add, list(dat$X0), z)), FUN=sum)
```