# summarize multiple dynamic columns and store results in new columns

Tags: r, dynamic, multiple-columns

I have the following situation.

```
    df <- rbind(
  data.frame(thisDate = rep(seq(as.Date("2018-1-1"), as.Date("2018-1-2"), by="day")) ),
  data.frame(thisDate = rep(seq(as.Date("2018-2-1"), as.Date("2018-2-2"), by="day")) ))
df <- cbind(df,lastMonth = as.Date(format(as.Date(df$thisDate - months(1)),"%Y-%m-01")))
df <- cbind(df, prod1Quantity= seq(1:4) )
```

I have quantities for different days of a month for an unknown number of products. I want to have 1 column for every product with the total monthly quantity of that product for all of the previous month. So the output would be like this .. ie grouped by lastMonth, Prod1Quantity . I just don't get how to group by, mutate and summarise  dynamically if that indeed is the right approach.

I came across [data.table generate multiple columns and summarize them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622608/data-table-generate-multiple-columns-and-summarize-them) . I think it appears to do what I need - but I just don't get how it is working!

**Desired Output**

```
   thisDate  lastMonth prod1Quantity prod1prevMonth
1 2018-01-01 2017-12-01             1             NA
2 2018-01-02 2017-12-01             2             NA
3 2018-02-01 2018-01-01             3              3
4 2018-02-02 2018-01-01             4              3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach could be

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

temp_df <- df %>%
  mutate(thisDate_forJoin = as.Date(format(thisDate,"%Y-%m-01"))) 

final_df <- temp_df %>%
  mutate(thisDate_forJoin = thisDate_forJoin %m-% months(1)) %>%
  left_join(temp_df %>%
              group_by(thisDate_forJoin) %>%
              summarise_if(is.numeric, sum), 
            by="thisDate_forJoin") %>%
  select(-thisDate_forJoin)
```

**Output is:**

```
    thisDate prod1Quantity.x prod2Quantity.x prod1Quantity.y prod2Quantity.y
1 2018-01-01               1              10              NA              NA
2 2018-01-02               2              11              NA              NA
3 2018-02-01               3              12               3              21
4 2018-02-02               4              13               3              21
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(thisDate = structure(c(17532, 17533, 17563, 17564
), class = "Date"), prod1Quantity = 1:4, prod2Quantity = 10:13), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
#    thisDate prod1Quantity prod2Quantity
#1 2018-01-01             1            10
#2 2018-01-02             2            11
#3 2018-02-01             3            12
#4 2018-02-02             4            13
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be reached by calculating the month-wise production quantity and then joining on `month` of `lastMonth` and `thisDate`.

`lubridate::month` function has been used evaluate month from date.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% group_by(month = as.integer(month(thisDate))) %>%
  summarise(prodQuantMonth = sum(prod1Quantity)) %>%
  right_join(., mutate(df, prevMonth = month(lastMonth)), by=c("month" = "prevMonth")) %>%
  select(thisDate, lastMonth, prod1Quantity, prodQuantLastMonth = prodQuantMonth)

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   thisDate   lastMonth  prod1Quantity prodQuantLastMonth
#   <date>     <date>             <int>              <int>
# 1 2018-01-01 2017-12-01             1                 NA
# 2 2018-01-02 2017-12-01             2                 NA
# 3 2018-02-01 2018-01-01             3                  3
# 4 2018-02-02 2018-01-01             4                  3
```

Comment: Thank you! I will  now try to extend it to a dynamic number of products as in prod1Quantity, prod2Quantity and so on. Thank you once again.